# Facebook API offline access

Tags: facebook, cron

I have a script I'd like to run via a cron job:

```
<?

require_once 'fb_access.php';

$user = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($user) {
      try {
        $page_id = '********';
        $page_info = $facebook->api("/$page_id?fields=access_token");
        if( !empty($page_info['access_token']) ) {
            $args = array(
                'access_token'  =>  $page_info['access_token'],
                'message'       =>  'This is the message',
                'link'          =>  'http://thisisthelink',
                'caption'       =>  'This is the caption',
                'description'   =>  'This is the description',
            );
            $post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
        }
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
      }
    }
   ?>
```

However when I try to run it via the cron job, it doesn't work.  I've figured out this has something to do with the offline_access token.  But from what I've read, a user must manually login to get the token.  As I'd like to run this via a cron job, that's not feasible.  Any ideas?

UPDATE:

I tried this; is it completely wrong?

```
require_once 'fb_access.php';

$user = $facebook->getUser();
$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

if ($user) {
    try {
        $page_id = '**********';
        $args = array(
            'access_token'  =>  $token,
            'message'       =>  'This is the message',
            'link'          =>  'http://thisisthelink',
            'caption'       =>  'This is the caption',
            'description'   =>  'This is the description',
        );
    $post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}
```

UPDATE #2:

```
<?php

require_once 'fb_access.php';

$user = $facebook->getUser();
$token = '*******LONG_ACCESS_TOKEN*******';

$page_id = '**********';
$args = array(
    'access_token'  =>  $token,
    'message'       =>  'This is the message',
    'link'          =>  'http://www.thisisthelink.com',
    'caption'       =>  'This is the caption',
    'description'   =>  'This is the description',
);

$post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);

?>
```

Using this I get: Fatal error: `Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action thrown in /base_facebook.php on line 1106`

Comment: Wait...  Now even this isn't working when I manually fire the script.  Help!  This is frustrating.

Comment: To your updatE: yes, it's wrong. You need to have an access token (logged in user) first. Look, go to this page `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/` and "Get access token" with manage_pages permissions there. After you got it, enter `/accounts/` into the address bar (in the page) and press submit. You should see your page and access token. Change `$facebook->getAccessToken()` from your code to that access token, stop trying to check `$user` and try again.

Comment: Hmm...  Trying to do this but i'm getting:

`{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#210) Subject must be a page.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 210
  }
}`

Comment: From what are you getting this error?

Comment: From the graph explorer.

Comment: when querying what page?

Comment: I think I get it now. I query my own user ID appended with /accounts/ to get the page access_token?

Comment: /me/accounts/ to get the page access token, yes. You'll see the access token in that output window

Comment: Yep.  Got it.  Check out out my update above.

Comment: I'm positive the app is authorized to do what I'm trying to do!

Comment: how did you solve the last update?

Comment: I haven't solved the problem yet; I'm still getting the error.

Comment: oh, well, you're still getting user's id - remove `$user = $facebook->getUser();`

Comment: I removed that to no avail.  I'm still getting the same error...

Comment: try the code I given you in my answer. It worked perfectly. Try to refresh the access token

Answer (score 3):

- First of all, you do not need offline_access, if you're requiring publish_stream permission.
- You need manage_pages permission if you want to login/manage/share as your page.
- You need user access token in order to get page access token. You need to authenticate once manually

```
header("Location: $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" => "publish_stream,manage_pages")));
```

- - After you get an access token, save it to the persistent place (file, for example)
- - When in need, get the access token from your file and use it (just add access_token to your arguments)

Following code worked to me:

```
<?php
include(dirname(__FILE__)."/fb/facebook.php");
define('PAGE_ID', '123456498798');
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '178645249555182',
  'secret' => 'csdf64sd65f4sd6f54f1c',
));

$a = array(
    'access_token'  => 'werf564s6d1cr98f965d6gf49w8sd49f87w9ed5c16d5f49s8f74w9e8rf74',
    'message'       =>  'This is the message',
    'caption'       =>  'This is the caption',
    'description'   =>  'This is the description'
);
print_r($facebook->api('/'.PAGE_ID.'/feed', 'post', $a));
```

Comment: Hmm...  My app has those permissions.  How do I **save** the access token?  Aren't I referencing it in the above code?

Comment: "How" => manually, for example. You get an access token with $facebook->getAccessToken() when user logs in

Comment: A user will never log in.  I want this script to pull from a database of pre-defined posts and post to a Facebook page via cron job.

See above.

Comment: @Andrew: as I said, `You need to authenticate once manually` .. you, as admin of the page. Nobody else, only you.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a cron job, there's no-one there to do authorization with.  You cannot do what you want.  You'll need to look for an alternative.

An alternative like taking a valid auth token from one of the page admins that you've requested the extended token for (offline_access is being quickly deprecated see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/).

This 60 day token will need to be put into some config that the cron job can access.

You will need to manually update the 60 day token every couple of months.

You can get valid access tokens from the https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer.

Comment: You can get valid access tokens from the https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer this was most important part for me!